# Norwegian organisasjonsnummer generator

Tags: java

I would like to know how to write the code in Java to generate a Norwegian organisasjonsnummer. I have found that http://prag.matisk.com/org/ generates valid organisasjonsnummer. But I am not sure how. Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: You probably do some research. To find out how/where these numbers are **specified**.

Comment: This question is not in the scope of this site. You want to know, how these numbers are generated. Well, programming is not your problem here. You need the algorithm, which can create a valid number. And SO is not the place to ask for an unknown algorithm.

Comment: This has been around for quite some time https://github.com/bekkopen/NoCommons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the linked site, (code is pretty understandable IMHO):

```
    var num1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    var num2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    var num3 = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    var num4 = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    var num5 = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    var num6 = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    var num7 = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    var num8 = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);

    // Weights: 3 2 7 6 5 4 3 2
    var weighted = num1*3 + num2*2 + num3*7 + num4*6 + num5*5 + num6*4 + num7*3 + num8*2;
    var remainder = weighted % 11;
    var contr = 11 - remainder;

    if (contr == 11)
        contr = 0;

    //alert("weighted: " + weighted + "\nremainder: " + remainder + "\ncontr: " + contr);

    if (contr == 10)
        return null; // invalid orgnr
    else
        return "" + num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5 + num6 + num7 + num8 + contr; // valid orgnr
```